# How do I save raw bytes into a file?

Tags: files, saving

I'm trying to make a .wav file generator in Emacs Lisp. I have some binary data, as a sequence of bytes:

```
(setq binary-data (list 62 236 60))
```

I would like to insert that data into a file. I expect that file to be three bytes long.

If I try to insert it into a buffer, then write that buffer to a file, I get a file that consists of four bytes:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (seq-doseq (char binary-data)
    (insert char))
  (write-region nil nil "~/char-inserted.wav"))

$ hd ~/char-inserted.wav
00000000  3e c3 ac 3c                                       |>..<|
00000004
```

So it seems like I'm having problems with inserting that single byte. I've also tried converting the data into a unibyte string, but that still gives me a four-byte file:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (seq-doseq (char (apply #'unibyte-string binary-data))
    (insert char))
  (write-region nil nil "~/unibyte-string.wav"))

$ hd ~/unibyte-string.wav
00000000  3e c3 ac 3c                                       |>..<|
00000004
```

I've also converted the unibyte string to a multibyte string:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (seq-doseq (char (string-as-multibyte (apply #'unibyte-string binary-data)))
    (insert char))
  (write-region nil nil "~/multibyte-string.wav"))
```

But this gives me an error:

```
> These default coding systems were tried to encode text
in the buffer ‘ *temp*-110101’:
  (utf-8-unix (2 . 4194284))
However, each of them encountered characters it couldn’t encode:
utf-8-unix cannot encode these:
```

It suggests I select one of the coding systems "raw-text" or "no-conversion", but I'm unsure how to do that, or if it will even help.

How do I save these three bytes into a file that ends up as a three-byte file? What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a minimum, if by default your buffers are multibyte, you will need to toggle this specific buffer to unibyte; you also need to set the file coding system of the buffer to `raw-text`:

```el
  (with-temp-buffer
    (toggle-enable-multibyte-characters)
    (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'raw-text)
    (seq-doseq (char binary-data)
      (insert char))
    (write-region nil nil "~/char-inserted.wav"))
```

You might also have to specify `no-conversion` for the write, but I'm not sure. Something like this perhaps:

```el
(let ((coding-system-for-write 'no-conversion))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (toggle-enable-multibyte-characters)
    (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'raw-text)
    (seq-doseq (char binary-data)
      (insert char))
    (write-region nil nil "~/char-inserted.wav")))
```

But there may be other gotcha's as well: it would be good to have an answer by an expert.

Comment: Thanks! With either of these, I still get a four-byte file. Do they result in a three-byte file for you? I'll play around with options for `coding-system-for-write`.

Comment: Missed something - edited.

Comment: Ah, it looks like `toggle-enable-multibyte-characters` was the secret! With that, I don't need either `coding-system-for-write` nor `set-buffer-file-coding-system`, at least to get this specific three-byte file. Thanks so much!

Comment: I suspect that in general, you will need all three: what I'm not sure about is whether you'll need more.